# Org-level self-hosted Github runner

Tags: github-actions, devops, runner

Struggling to deploy self-hosted runner on org-level. All prerequisites like token, cert-manger, controller itself all in place, but when I deploy the runner its not scaling up. Manager of controller gives messages below.

```
 2023-11-23T08:28:25Z    DEBUG    runnerreplicaset    Skipped reconcilation because owner is not synced yet    {"runnerreplicaset": │
│  "actions-runner-controller/orglevel-gh-runner-wzx5r", "owner": "actions-runner-controller/orglevel-gh-runner-wzx5r-wgf6f" │
│ , "pods": null}
```

The most annoying part that if I deploy it with same configuration but instead organization I specify repository everything works well.

Tried user another token, tried introducing horizontal runner autoscaler, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

[Upgrade](https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller/blob/master/charts/actions-runner-controller/docs/UPGRADING.md) from 0.22.0 to 0.23.5 helped

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).